# How to get grails plugin version from app?

Tags: grails, version, grails-plugin

How to get grails plugin version from app?

Details: my app is also a grails plugin.

When I set version, using

> grails set-version 0.5

I can't get value using `grailsApplication.metadata['app.version']`
because value is updated in my FooBarGrailsPlugin.groovy class

The **application.properties** file remains unchanged.

Tks.

---

When I run set-version, my class change from:

```
class FooBarGrailsPlugin {
    def version = 0.1
}
```

to

```
class FooBarGrailsPlugin {
    def version = 0.5
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will print out the name and version of all plugins installed in an app

```
applicationContext.getBean('pluginManager').allPlugins.each {plugin ->
    println "${plugin.name} - ${plugin.version}"
}
```

Comment: Not working yet. I'm in a Controller, and applicationContext cames null. I changed to `ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext` and is getting plugin, but value still came from `FooBarGrailsPlugin` class, not the `application.properties` file.

Comment: I saw `SetVersion.groovy` source code and there is this conditional: `if (isPluginProject) { ..change class...} else { ...change properties file... }` . That's why I'm changing value of class, not file. Seems that a plugin project can't be versioned as a normal project. Well, thanks a lot.

Comment: A grails project is either a plugin or an application, it can't be both as you suggested in your question

Comment: My application is also a plugin (not used as a plugin, but has plugins configurations). Maybe this usage is unexpected by grails creators...

Comment: ultimately, if there's a plugin config file `ProjectNamePlugin.groovy` in the root dir, then it's a plugin, otherwise it's not

Comment: Ok, So I will "des-pluginizer" my app, so it won't be a plugin anymore. Tks Don!